# Xvnc and Lightdm connect to primary display :0 and login remotely

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, xorg, vnc

I'd like to enable remote VNC login to a lightdm session on debian so I can login remotely. I've uncommented the `[VNCServer]` in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and then restarted `lightdm.service`

```
[VNCServer]
enabled=true
command=/usr/bin/Xvnc
port=5900
width=1024
height=768
depth=8

root@deb2:~# systemctl restart lightdm.service
```

Port 5900 is now open and lightdm is listening

```
root@deb2:~# ss -ltnpu
Netid     State      Recv-Q     Send-Q                                Local Address:Port          Peer Address:Port     Process                                       
......
tcp       LISTEN     0          10                                          0.0.0.0:5900               0.0.0.0:*         users:(("lightdm",pid=1622,fd=11))
```

I create a local SSH tunnel and then connect remotely using `vncviewer`:

```
admin@:~$ ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 root@192.168.1.109


admin@:~$ vncviewer -Log *:stderr:100 127.0.0.1:5900


TigerVNC Viewer 64-bit v1.10.1
Built on: 2020-04-09 06:49
Copyright (C) 1999-2019 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.rst)
See https://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.

Fri Apr 29 14:29:48 2022
 DecodeManager: Detected 2 CPU core(s)
 DecodeManager: Creating 2 decoder thread(s)
 TcpSocket:   Connecting to 192.168.1.241 [192.168.1.241] port 5900
 CConn:       Connected to host 192.168.1.241 port 5900
 CConnection: reading protocol version
 CConn:       End of stream
```

As you can see the VNC connects but then immediately exit.

In the lightdm logs `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log` ([paste is here](http://dpaste.com/53FEA5ZE3)) I see the connection is received and the display server is started but then it seems to immediately shutdown.

***I'd also like to actually connect to the display that is actually running on the local machine (Ie. Display :0) instead of create a new display*** which seems to be what is happening here:

```
[+27.51s] DEBUG: Launching process 2119: /usr/bin/Xvnc :1 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:1 -nolisten tcp -inetd -geometry 1024x768 -depth 8
[+27.52s] DEBUG: XServer 1: Waiting for ready signal from X server :1
```

As you can see Xvnc is being called with the display# :1 and not :0 which is what i want

`/usr/bin/Xvnc :1 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:1 -nolisten tcp -inetd -geometry 1024x768 -depth 8`

I'd really appreciate any ideas about how I can get this working, Thanks!

```
[+27.51s] DEBUG: Got VNC connection from 127.0.0.1:44548
[+27.51s] DEBUG: Seat vnc1: Loading properties from config section Seat:*
[+27.51s] DEBUG: Seat vnc1: Starting
[+27.51s] DEBUG: Seat vnc1: Creating greeter session
[+27.51s] DEBUG: Seat vnc1: Creating display server of type x
[+27.51s] DEBUG: XServer 1: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-1.log
[+27.51s] DEBUG: XServer 1: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:1
[+27.51s] DEBUG: XServer 1: Launching X Server
[+27.51s] DEBUG: Launching process 2119: /usr/bin/Xvnc :1 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:1 -nolisten tcp -inetd -geometry 1024x768 -depth 8
[+27.52s] DEBUG: XServer 1: Waiting for ready signal from X server :1
[+27.52s] DEBUG: Registering seat with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat2
[+27.55s] DEBUG: Process 2119 exited with return value 1
[+27.55s] DEBUG: XServer 1: X server stopped
[+27.55s] DEBUG: XServer 1: Removing X server authority /var/run/lightdm/root/:1
[+27.55s] DEBUG: Seat vnc1: Display server stopped
[+27.55s] DEBUG: Seat vnc1: Stopping session
[+27.55s] DEBUG: Seat vnc1: Session stopped
[+27.55s] DEBUG: Seat vnc1: Stopping display server, no sessions require it
[+27.55s] DEBUG: Seat vnc1: Stopping; greeter display server failed to start
[+27.55s] DEBUG: Seat vnc1: Stopping
[+27.55s] DEBUG: Seat vnc1: Stopped



root@deb2:~# update-alternatives --query Xvnc
Name: Xvnc
Link: /usr/bin/Xvnc
Slaves:
 Xvnc.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/Xvnc.1.gz
Status: auto
Best: /usr/bin/Xtigervnc
Value: /usr/bin/Xtigervnc

Alternative: /usr/bin/Xtigervnc
Priority: 80
Slaves:
 Xvnc.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/Xtigervnc.1.gz
root@deb2:~# 
root@deb2:/var/log/lightdm# ls -lat /usr/bin/Xvnc lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Apr 26 11:04 /usr/bin/Xvnc -> /etc/alternatives/Xvnc
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem has to do with the default
-depth 8 argument that gets added to the Xvnc invocation.  Support for 8 bit depth has been removed in recent versions.  See: https://github.com/canonical/lightdm/pull/265/commits/02e3d25724a9df88631b4c7c5f0dab409db6a0a2.

I had the same problem, resulting in a fatal error of the X server (bundled along Xvnc).

Answer (score 0):

No idea why this wasn't working but I have achieved want i wanted using xinetd

On your work machine, `apt-get install xinetd tigervnc-standalone-server` and edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` to include the following lines:

```
[XDMCPServer]
enabled=true
port=177
listen-address=localhost
```

Create `/etc/xinetd.d/Xvnc` with the following content:

```
service xvnc_1
{
    type = UNLISTED
    disable = no
    protocol = tcp
    socket_type = stream
    bind = 127.0.0.1
    port = 5900
    wait = yes
    user = root
    server = /usr/bin/Xvnc
    server_args = :1 -inetd -query localhost -geometry 1600x1200 -depth 24 -once -fp /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc -DisconnectClients=0 -NeverShared -SecurityTypes None
}
```

To enable listen on all interface remove lines from above:

```
listen-address=localhost
bind = 127.0.0.1
```

Now restart xinetd and lightdm: `systemctl restart xinetd lightdm`

Source: https://users.dcs.aber.ac.uk/auj/en/office-remote-linux/

In addition, to disable any authentication messages see the following article about setting the correct polkit policies: https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12073

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).